# ASP.net MVC and .Net version

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have visual studio 2008 installed on my PC. Can anyone tell me what should I get installed so that I can start with the MVC architecture. I am very much confused about the .NET versions required for MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to http://www.asp.net

you will need vs2008 with SP1

.net3.5

then the [beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A24D1E00-CD35-4F66-BAA0-2362BDDE0766&displaylang=en) from MS